# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-common:+

Tags: android, jwplayer

I am using the `Android` code provided by **`JWPlayer`** https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer-sdk-android-demo. When do I compile this project then I am getting following error.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-common:+.

Could not resolve com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-common:+.
Required by:
    project :app

> Could not resolve com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-common:+.
>   Failed to list versions for com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-common.
>   Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://mvn.jwplayer.com/content/repositories/releases/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/jwplayer-common/maven-metadata.xml.
>   Could not HEAD 'https://mvn.jwplayer.com/content/repositories/releases/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/jwplayer-common/maven-metadata.xml'.
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed
>   PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed
>   timestamp check failed
>   NotAfter: Sat Nov 11 19:48:03 IST 2017

Comment: same issue in my project

Comment: mvn.jwplayer.com seems to have wrong ssl certificate.

Comment: I have the same issues but starts today :/

Comment: Access mvn.jwplayer.com in a browser, and you'll catch what I want to say in previous comment. It's not a problem of demo.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the SSL Certificate had expired for `mvn.jwplayer.com.` It is now back online as I have successfully built my Android Studio project with `Maven`.

Future reference, you can always use the **`AAR’s`** to build your Android Studio Project available in your `JWPlayer` Dashboard or use the HTTP version of our `Maven` domain.

```
maven {
      url ‘http://mvn.jwplayer.com/content/repositories/releases/’
}
```